# How to automate the bitbucket repository to databricks repos by using ci/cd pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, databricks, databricks-repos

Can someone help on this how to automate the ci/cd pipeline to update and create new files in databricks repos from bitbucket repositories..

Comment: What do you mean under update & create? Sync content of the BitBucket into Repos?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync changes from BitBucket repository into Databricks Repos, then you have following possibilities:

- Use `databricks repos update` command of the [databricks-cli package](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/repos-cli.html), like this:

```sh
databricks repos update --path /Repos/user/repository --branch <branch_name>
```

- Use [Update command of Repos API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/repos.html#operation/update-repo), but it's too low-level because it doesn't work with paths, and you need to know Repository ID that could obtained via [Workspace API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#get-status). So it's several commands instead of single one:

```sh
curl -s -n -X GET -o /tmp/staging-repo-info.json "$DATABRICKS_HOST/api/2.0/workspace/get-status" -H "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN" -d '{"path":"/Repos/Staging/databricks-nutter-projects-demo"}'
export STAGING_REPOS_ID=$(cat /tmp/staging-repo-info.json|grep '"object_type":"REPO"'|sed -e 's|^.*"object_id":\([0-9]*\).*$|\1|')
curl -s -n -X PATCH -o "/tmp/$(Build.SourceBranchName)-out.json" "$DATABRICKS_HOST/api/2.0/repos/$STAGING_REPOS_ID" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN" -d "{\"branch\": \"$(Build.SourceBranchName)\"}"
```

P.S. You can find end-to-end CI/CD demo with Repos and Azure DevOps in [this repository](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo). Although it's not a BitBucket, but the structure of the pipeline remains the same.

Comment: Any guide for deploying to AWS?

Comment: it's the same for all clouds